# what is the perfect way to implement textStyle and colors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, styles, themes

I wanna implement theme and style and colors in professional and centralized way noting that I support dark theme,I saw many approaches using themeData but I need one to support different colors based on the appearance mode

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no single way to do this. Each project can implement this solution in a different way. I have an example, but in this case it depends on the flutter_modular package. Maybe that gives you a new idea.

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter App',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
    secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.cyan,
    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
          bodyText2: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
                color: Colors.cyan,
              ),
        ),
    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.roboto().fontFamily,
  ),
).modular();
```

You can use a conditional to chose the theme.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I understand what you said but I'm thinking about what is the perfect way to this, I have the two modes and a lot of icons which their colors will change based on appearance mode,
I'm thinking to create 2 classes first one for customize the theme and the second one contains all other colors as static variables and that is for the colors which are not supported by themeData like icons colors and containers colors etc..
but I'm wondering if there is a better way before start doing this approach.

Comment: MaterialApp has a property called darkTheme.

Comment: yes but this property like the normal theme proberty they are not support colors only some  like primary and secondary and some extra but the app icons contains more colors noting that I'm using icons as font awesome 
that means I'm coloring every icon